# How can two data sets have the same power?

Tags: r, anova, statistical-power

I'm doing one-way ANOVA power calculations (in R) for an RCBD trial with 15 groups, 3 blocks, and n = 3 per group. How is it possible that two different ANOVA models have exactly the same power even if the response variables are different? Even if the responses are somewhat related, I don't understand why the power is the same even to 7 significant figures. The fact that the power is very low makes sense.

Here are the calculations for two possible responses:

```
     groups = 15
          n = 3
between.var = 0.3422844 
 within.var = 1.026853
  sig.level = 0.01
      power = 0.2162478

     groups = 15
          n = 3
between.var = 1.759788
 within.var = 5.279365
  sig.level = 0.01
      power = 0.2162478
```

Comment: well, if your design is indeed the same for your two models (i.e. the degrees of freedom are the same), and since the ratio of the between:within variance is almost identical in your two datasets (0.3333334 and 0.3333333), then power is going to be almost identical, or given a certain precision (7 decimals here), power is going to be identical... don't know why the between and within variances would have virtually the same ratio across datasets for 2 different DVs, but given that they are, then power will be the same.

Comment: Seems a remarkable coincidence unless there's something else.  Could you give any details on the two different response variables?  Also, how are you calculating the power? (always possible something wrong there).

Comment: Power to detect what? It only makes sense to compute power to detect some hypothetical effect that must be stated.

Comment: The response variables (of which there 13 total) are all different measurements about plants. I checked to see that the responses are not highly correlated-- far from being combinations of each other. By calculating the power I was hoping to quantify the probability of correctly rejecting the null hypothesis that the 7 varieties of plants are the same. This is part of a pilot/preliminary study so that I can most efficiently adjust sample sizes to accommodate the varying effect sizes for different response variables.